# slides and mega menu not working for not logged in users

Tags: wordpress, optimization, caching, elementor

i have a wordpress (woocommerce) site with hello elemntor theme.
not logged in users can see site mega menus and product grids correctly
[this is how they see my megamenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtXWZ.png)
[this is how they see the products grid but the arrows keys dont work for them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE6ZU.png)
the thing is there is no problem in loading these for logged in users .
im usnig wp3total cache plugind and autooptimize and async as a plugin.
is there any css or java ineed to exclude or sth?

i tried lots of caching plugins like litespeed or ... but these are the best plugins working for me .
i tried re designing the headers and footers of my site but nothing changed.

Comment: It looks like you have messed up a setting making it a mega menu after the site has been cached, Because the cached version shows the correct mega menu and when you are logged in it does not show the cached version and thus shows you the broken version. Go through the mega menu settings and see if its all configured correctly

Comment: thanks for the response .it happened just when I checked the box for minifying and aggregating CSS in auto optimizer plugin

Comment: Try to disable the minification of your css then, if it works afterwards just leave it off as minifying CSS doesn't have alot of effect on performance. If you have a huge css file however you can always check another plugin to minify your css as some plugins are more aggressive with minification then others.

Comment: exactly i change my plugin to wp rocket and worked smoothly